# glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog return empty or null data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, amazon-athena, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have used terraform to create the glue crawler to crawl over the dynamodb and created an ETL job to create the glue context. I am able to query the athena table. The issue is when I am trying to create a new job that queries the glue table using the dataframe returns null or empty value.

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

Was the crawler run before the job attempted to pull data from_catalog?